# Choosing points from Matlab contour function

Tags: matlab, contour

I was wondering how I can view point values off a contour plot.

I wish to obtain all the x-positions at the initial time, t=0 from my contour plot. Can this be done?

I have read on this forum about Choosing isolines from Matlab contour function however I wish to get the actual points.

Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: See this [topic](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38863-extract-contour-data-from-contour-matrix-c/content/contourdata.m) to extract point coordinates from a contour matrix output by `contour`

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but recall it to be something like this:

```
h = findobj(gcf,'Type','Line');
x = get(h,'XData');
y = get(h,'YData');
```